# Authentication failed when logging openam authenticated with ldap

Tags: tomcat, ldap, integration, openam

when checked in authentication.error logs
 authentication -200 LDAP not available .Also here displayed cn and dn values are are different not matching with values that we configured with ldap server settings in openam configurations .

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are authenticating with the correct realm?
Or have you checked your datastore configuration?

http://openam.example.com/openam?realm=myrealm

Comment: i have config openam with default settings and logged  with amadmin details for configuring our ldap details for authentication. but when i checked the config folder for  authLdap.xml files it is showing the default settings instead of our ldap config ...please can you suggest us the procedure for configuring openam with our ldap details  ...  
Thanks in advance

Comment: Here we are trying to config openldap details to openam for a1uthentication purpose .

Comment: You actually configure a new lady datastore in openam and that is configurable by the web interface not via the cal files. You San also configure this vis the ssoadm config took if it is installed.

Comment: Sorry for the typos above.  If you are using the Datastore authentication module in the authentication chain, as it would be configured by default then you should be able to authenticate.  You should be able to see the users you can authenticate with under the subjects tab.

Comment: Hai , thanks for your valuable reply .. 
 
Now i am able to see ldap users list in subjects tab of openam .. 
But when i am login with ldap user then i am getting as "Authentication failed issue " (when login with sign with Ldap Authentication login page).

In Authentication.error logs .. showing as invalid password error for  user .... authentication -201 

Please can you suggest me solution .